# Retrieve StyleUrl value when a grid is clicked on a kml on googlemaps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

Is there a way to get the value of the styleUrl tag from the KmlEvent?
I have a kml displayed on the googlemaps, and when I click on any of the grid/polygon in the kml, I need to get the styleUrl tag value associated with it. Is there a way to get it?

Answer (score 0):

With the native Google Maps Javascript API v3 it is not (currently) possible to access the styleUrl of the current placemark.  One option (if your KML is simple enough) would be a third party parser like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/)

[example using geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_categories_linktoA.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/nzhistory_net_nzmap_locations_kml.xml)